# EditTextPreference cannot be set

Tags: android

i have this code to set an EditTextPreference when i tap on a menu item:

```
 case R.id.prochain_vidange:

         settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
        km = settings.getString("km", "");
        Log.d("TAG",km);
       int x= Integer.valueOf(km);
       int y= x+8000;
       String z=String.valueOf(y);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = settings.edit();
        Log.d("proch1",z);
        editor1.putString("prochain_vidange",z);
        Log.d("proch2",z);
        editor1.commit();


        return true;
```

I really don't know why when i tap on the menu item nothing happens, the calculated value (y  converted to string z) cannot be set to "km" EditTextPreference. (settings and km values i used them before in another menu item.)
What's going on with this code ?
Thank you very much.
EDIT:

```
08-11 21:32:16.006: DEBUG/TAG(2394): 4000
08-11 21:32:16.016: DEBUG/proch1(2394): 12000
08-11 21:32:16.016: DEBUG/proch2(2394): 12000
```

Comment: You should really check your LogCat. Is the issue - km is not in SharedPrefs so it is returning "" and this cannot be parsed to an int. So your LogCat should say 'NumberFormatException'

Comment: @Blundell: km is returning the right value! I noticed that sometimes the value showen is right in "prochain_vidange" and sometimes not. Perhaps variables allocation :\

Comment: add lines like Log.i("SomeTag", "km is:"+km); through your code, you can then check as your going what is going on using LogCat

Comment: Yes i made it and it's displaying the right value, exactly as it's set in tht EditTextPreference.

Comment: Show edit your question and show us your LogCat! We still don't know what the error is.

Comment: @androniennn let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2386/discussion-between-blundell-and-androniennn)

Answer (score 4):

```
EditTextPreference myEditTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("prochain_vidange");
myEditTextPreference.setText(z);
```